# Carthage Xcode 9 Error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, frameworks, carthage

I try to install Carthage in my project but it always crash on launch.

Nothing works from what I've tried..

Error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/StarscreamSocketIO.framework/StarscreamSocketIO
Referenced from: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/69ADA4FD-59A0-4840-9A64-XXXXX/XXXX.app/Frameworks/SocketIO.framework/SocketIO
Reason: image not found
```

Carthage folder:

[image]

Linked Frameworks and Libraries:
[image]

Run Script:
[image]

Copy Files:
[image]

I also tried to set the framework in Embedded Binaries.

Thank you.

Edit: Cartfile file: 
[image]

Comment: can you publish the content of your "Cartfile" ?

Comment: Yes, I added to post

Comment: have u add this to `Build phases` -> `Embed frameworks` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Swift 3**

If you can't port your code to Swift 4, the following is a possible workaround:

1.inside your main project, drag and drop the file Starscream.xcodeproj which is inside:

```
Carthage/Checkouts/socket.io-client-swift/Source/Starscream
```

2.add the framework StarscreamSocketIO.framework inside the section "Linked Frameworks and Libraries"

3.compile and run

**Swift 4**

socket.io v11 had a bug with Carthage: 
[github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-swift/issues/787](http://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-swift/issues/787) 
although it's possible to fix it with some manual workarounds, I recommend you to upgrade to the latest socket.io v13

Comment: But I use swift 3 and V13+ is swift 4.

Comment: modified the answer with a possible workaround for Swift 3